# Hibernate - join ElementCollection with the rest of an entity fetch query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have major performance issues when I try to map an entity into a response.

This is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "someOtherId", nullable = false)
    private String someOtherId;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Phones", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myEntityId"))
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private List<String> phones; // <------- we care about this

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Websites", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myEntityId"))
    @Column(name = "websites")
    private List<String> websites; // <------- we care about this

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "myEntity")
    private List<ContactEntity> bbb;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "myEntity")
    private List<AddressEntity> ccc;

}
```

This is how I use the DAL to fetch it:

```
List<MyEntity> findByTenantIdAndIdIn(String someOtherId, Set<String> MyEntityIds);
```

Now when I iterate over `List<MyEntity>` to map it, and call `myEntity.getPhones()`, I see that a DB call is being made, which is what causes the slowdown, a 70 seconds slowdown on 1000 entities.
So what can I do to force it to `join` in the first query it did when I called `findByTenantIdAndIdIn`?

Notes:

- `Phones` is a simple table with columns: [myEntityId, phone]
- The same problem happens with `Websites`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with it being an `@ElementCollection`. Like you figured out, you can use subselect fetching or could also use a batch size for select fetching(the default strategy). Another possibility is to use a fetch join in the query, but be careful when fetch joining multiple collections as that might create a cartesian product which leads to a performance problem cause by too many rows being transfered. A fetch join example HQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT e FROM MyEntity e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.phones LEFT JOIN FETCH e.websites
```

Comment: What about turning them into entities instead of ElementCollection?

Comment: What do you mean with "What about"? Could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: I meant changing `Phones` and `Websites` to be entities too, could this improve performance even more?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know for sure, but I doubt that `@Fetch(SUBSELECT)` only works for entities. I think this works for element collections as well.

Comment: Using HQL query like this was the only thing that helped forcing Hibernate to do JOIN instead of Subselect on ElementCollection...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it right after I posted this.

I annotated phones and websites with `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` which creates a parallel subquery.

Another way to solve this is simply to not use `@ElementCollection` because it has bad performance, use an Entity instead as they recommend in the video here: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-query-elementcollection/